# How to add precompiled PHP to Apache?

Tags: php, apache, web, centos

Basically, I needed to build (via make and make install) PHP by myself with some extra parameters. It is running well, I tested it with php test.php on PHP script file. Back then I did not need to use it with Apache (which is installed via yum) but now I do.

How can I enable self-made PHP in Apache? I can not find any .so files associated with PHP in my system.

PHP version: 5.4.36
Apache version: 2.4.6
OS: CentOS 7

Thanks!

Comment: PHP is not really a compiled language.

Comment: @apokryfos I mean compiled binaries of PHP itself.

Comment: That makes much more sense. Check https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/lamp/lamp-on-centos-7 (PHP section) it may help.

Comment: @apokryfos The problem is that I already have PHP installed on system. All I need is to integrate (or enable it in some way, lol) on Apache, which is installed too. I **can not** use other version of PHP or install it via _yum_ because required PHP extension can only run on this version and needs PHP to be compiled with it.

Comment: What I would do is do a manual compiling from source. You need to compile the PHP module into Apache and that needs to be done manually if you have a specific PHP version you need to use. Check http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php